# How to count months between two date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

When I try to count months between 2 dates I get the wrong result.

```
SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('23/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),
       TO_DATE('26/10/2014','dd/mm/yyyy')))  
FROM dual;


SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('25/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'), 
       TO_DATE('05/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'))) 
FROM dual;
```

I have to get in the first code - 4
on the second - 1
but I didn't get that.

Comment: what did you get then?

Comment: i want to get 4 and 1

Comment: 10/2014, 11/2014, 12/2015 , 01/2015 = 4 months

Comment: This question is similar to yours, might help you:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926923/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-2-given-dates-using-a-query][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926923/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-2-given-dates-using-a-query

Comment: You haven't really explained the logic here -- we can only guess at what you mean. Do you mean that you want to know how many calendar months there are, including the month of the first date and the month of the last date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finaly i get it:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(TO_DATE('23/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),'mm'),TRUNC(TO_DATE('15/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),'mm')))) + 1 FROM dual ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select       
  trunc( months_between(TO_DATE('2015/01/23','yyyy/mm/dd'),
       TO_DATE('2014/10/26','yyyy/mm/dd')) ) mths    
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Now you can check this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('26/10/2014','dd/mm/yyyy'),TO_DATE('23/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
       ))  
FROM dual;
 -3 
10/2014 to 11/2014 -- 1
11/2014 to 12/2015 -- 1
12/2015 to 01/2015 -- 1
so its 3. 
SELECT ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('05/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),TO_DATE('25/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') 
       )) 
FROM dual;
-1
```

Comment: hey thanks but it's  not what i need. 10/2014, 11/2014, 12/2015 , 01/2015 = 4 months

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
ceil(months_between(add_months(
      trunc(to_date('23/01/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM'),1)-1, --last day of  month
      trunc(to_date('26/10/2014','dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM')) --first_day of month
    ) months_between
    from dual;


select
      ceil(months_between(add_months(
            trunc(to_date('25/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM'),1)-1, --last day of  month
            trunc(to_date('05/05/2015','dd/mm/yyyy'),'MM'))--first_day of month
            ) months_between
from dual;
```

It returns 4 and 1.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1572)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(DATE '2015-01-23')+1,     -- 1st of next month
                    TRUNC(DATE'2014-10-26', 'mon')) -- 1st of month
 ,MONTHS_BETWEEN(LAST_DAY(DATE '2015-05-25')+1, 
                    TRUNC(DATE'2015-05-05', 'mon'))
FROM DUAL;
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1576)