# How to print range of weeks using pl sql query in a particular format?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, range, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have one date field that I am getting from one table the field is supervisor_Date(which is usually a Saturday). The requirement is to print the week ranges in Initial mm/dd/yyyy- final mm/dd/yyyy format starting from the week of supervisor date's next sunday to next week range from sysdate. So for example if supervisor date is 22nd April and sysdate is 15/05/2017. Code should print 23/04/2017-29/04/2017,30/04/2017-06/05/2017,07/05/2017-13/05/2017,14/05/2017-20/05/2017 and 21/05/2017-27/05/2017.

Can anyone help with this as I am stuck on how to proceed
?

HElp much appreciated.

Comment: I would start with making a step by step plan what your program needs to do. Make a list for your self. For example: First you need to fetch the data from the table.

Comment: that's been done I got the initial date which will act as the starting week's start date. Stuck on the second part of handling the week range printing using dual table

Comment: Maybe this example will give you an idea: `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'day') WeekDay, TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(SYSDATE,'sunday'),'iw') WeekNumber 
FROM   Dual;` This will print the weekday and weeknumber of today.

Comment: Thank you for this.But the thing is I cant seem to find a way to iterate the weeks from start to end

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926923/how-to-get-a-list-of-months-between-2-given-dates-using-a-query) will help you. Similar one.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

What a tough nut to crack. Managed to build some working code, being stretched by daughters.

```
select
  listagg(fin.current_date, '-') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY fin.group_col) "date_intervals"
from(
  select
    out_tmp.current_date,
    to_char(out_tmp.current_date,'D') week_day,
    ceil(rownum/2) group_col
  from(
    select 
      tmp.start_date,
      tmp.end_date,
      tmp.start_date + level current_date,
      to_char(tmp.start_date + level,'D') week_day
    from(
      select 
        to_date('2017-04-22','yyyy/mm/dd') start_date,
        trunc(sysdate) + 14 end_date
      from 
        dual) tmp
    where
      to_char(tmp.start_date + level,'D') in ('6','7')
    connect by level <= tmp.end_date - tmp.start_date + 1) out_tmp
  where
    out_tmp.current_date > out_tmp.start_date + (to_char(out_tmp.start_date,'D') - 6)*(-1) and
    out_tmp.current_date + 6 < out_tmp.end_date +(to_char(out_tmp.end_date,'D') - 7) * (-1) - 1) fin
group by
  fin.group_col;
```

Its brings the needed output. Hope it helps or at-least give some insights.
Good luck!